# Raw CAN data from OBD2

Tags: obd-ii

I am new to OBD 2. I want to get RAW CAN data from my vehicle(Duster from Renault,India). I am using OBDlink connector. Basically my question is how to extract only CAN data from vehicle OBD connector? I want to get the data from CAN. Is this possible?

Any comments are appreciable.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you mean by "raw CAN data" this may not be possible with common OBD connectors. With these, you can only access diagnostic = OBD data but not the raw CAN bus data of the vehicle (which is commonly 500kbit/s and thus faster than the adapters support anyway).

Comment: Then what should be the solution to get data from CAN bus of vehicle

Comment: Maybe a dedicated USB<->CAN interface, like e.g. [this one](http://www.fischl.de/usbtin/) or [this](http://www.can232.com/?page_id=14).

Comment: thanks I will try that

Comment: ATMA is the obdlink command for monitoring all I believe

Answer (score 0):

Cheapest best option IMO is a Teensy with CAN bus shield you can read more about here: https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/VeJFD9qA

The other off the shelve option would be to use an OBDLink SX adapter, they can support reading at the commonly used 500kbps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about receiving all CAN data and not losing any frames, you should buy a SocketCAN-capable CAN adapter. These do not pipe all the frames through serial ICs like ELM327 or STNxxxx and allow for better bandwidth.